# how to center php paginator with css

Tags: php, css, paginator

I'm trying to center my paginator.
I keep trying different things but it either goes all the way to the right, or it doesn't get centered.

This is my code :

```php
<?php
  $pagination = $products->pagination();?>
    <?php foreach($pagination->range(10)as $r): ?>
      <div class="paginator">
        <ul>
          <li><a<?php if($pagination->page() == $r) echo ' ' ?> href="<?php echo $pagination->pageURL($r) ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
?>
```

and here is my css

```css
.paginator {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  /*left:0;*/
  /*right:0;*/
}

.paginator li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .5s;
  border: thin solid #2A4143;
  /*border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;*/
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: inline;
  /*display: block;*/
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
  /*margin-right: auto;*/
  /*max-height: 100px;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

Comment: try using  `margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important;` maybe something is overwriting your css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to `.paginator` and remove `float: left;` from `.paginator li`

EDIT: added a container for all the paginators and then made `.paginator` to `disply: inline-block;` and added `text-align: center;` to the new container in CSS. Also remove `width: 100%;` from `.paginator`

Also to note, make that container outside of your foreach loop.

See working example here:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}


.paginator {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  /*left:0;*/
  /*right:0;*/
}

.paginator li {
  padding: 5px 8px 8px 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .5s;
  border: thin solid #2A4143;
  /*border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;*/
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  display: inline;
  /*display: block;*/
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
  /*margin-right: auto;*/
  /*max-height: 100px;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="paginator">
          <ul>
            <li><a>Echo'd PHP stuff here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      <div class="paginator">
          <ul>
            <li><a>Echo'd PHP stuff here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="paginator">
          <ul>
            <li><a>Echo'd PHP stuff here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: neither of these solutions are helping. can you post the link for the working example?

Comment: @HeidiE The working example is in my answer, click Run code snippet at the bottom.  And can you be more clear on what is not working?

Comment: if I remove float left, the result is the numbers of the paginator go one on top of the other, instead of being horizontal. Would it help if I post the code for the entire page @John ?

Comment: @HeidiE I have updated my answer, please take a look.